# Change hcharts( ) bars from solid-colored to gradient

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to make my `highcharter` plot (for an R Shiny dashboard) prettier by making the colors a gradient between two shades of green. I've made the following basic example using the default `pokemon` dataset in `highcharter`.

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)

#Subset the data into the pokemon that are Grass and Poison
grass_subset <- subset(pokemon, type_1 == "grass" & type_2 == "poison")

#Define the chart parameters
grass_poison_chart <- hchart(grass_subset, type = "column", hcaes(x=pokemon, y=base_experience))

#Define theme elements
myTheme <- hc_theme(
  colors = c('#658D1B', '84BD00', 'white'),
  chart = list(
    backgroundColor = "white"    
  ))

#Apply theme to grass_poison_chart
grass_poison_chart %>% hc_add_theme(myTheme)
```

Yielding

[image]

**The problem is that I don't know the way to make the bars colored with a gradient.** I tried to change my definition of `myTheme` to the following:

```
 myTheme <- hc_theme(
   color = list(
     linearGradient = (0,0,0,1),
     stops = (0, '#658D1B'),(1, '#84BD00')
   )
  )
```

In a naive attempt to simply copy the `highcharts` syntax:

```
color: {
    linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
    stops: [
        [0, '#658D1B'],
        [1, '#84BD00']
    ]
}
```

and change it into parentheses, but I genuinely didn't know where to go from here. I know what I did probably wasn't going to work (and it doesn't), but is something like this possible in `highcharter`? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for a late reply, I've had some problems with R installation.

The first thing I did was to attempt to code this in pure JS. This part was easy: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/byht9jd6

I thought that a little bit harder is implementing it in R, but.. this part was easy too :)
Here is a code:

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)

#Subset the data into the pokemon that are Grass and Poison
grass_subset <- subset(pokemon, type_1 == "grass" & type_2 == "poison")

#Define the chart parameters
grass_poison_chart <- hchart(grass_subset, type = "column", hcaes(x=pokemon, 
y=base_experience)) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(
    column = list(
      color = list(
        linearGradient = list(x1 = 0, x2 = 0, y1 = 0, y2 = 1),
        stops = list(
          c(0, '#658D1B'),
          c(1, '#84BD00')
        )
      )
    )
  )

#Apply theme to grass_poison_chart
grass_poison_chart %>% hc_add_theme(myTheme)
```

Comment: This works perfectly! I was able to adapt it to my code really easily. I honestly wasn't aware that one could simply translate code from highcharts into highcharter. Clearly I was doing something wrong!